# How to store comma seperated checked checkbox value in hidden field on button click event?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I want to store checked checkbox value in to my hidden field but i am not getting value.

I have 1 hidden field name as `Storecheckvalue` and i want to store my checked checkbox value in to this hidden field as comma seperated.

This is my Fiddle:
[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n08645j1/2/)

Comment: sorry posted old js fiddle link.Updated

Comment: JavaScript or JQuery? Code differs a lot for each.

Comment: @nvartak:i have updated my js fiddle link.Please check once again

Comment: Got it -> So I updated your tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the join function to join a array of values:

```
  var values = [];

  $('[id^="chk"]:checked:not("#chkAll"):not("[id^="chkParent"]")').each(function() {
    values.push($(this).val());
  });

  alert(values.join());
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/1kemunrt/2/

or for random id use a class for the controls

```
<input class="not" type="checkbox" id="chkAll" onchange="Checkallcheckbox(this)" runat="server" value="Parent" />
<br /> ---------Section 1 -----------
<div id="section1">
  <input type="hidden" value="" id="Storecheckvalue" />
  <li class="carousel-border">
    <input class="not" type="checkbox" id="chkParent1" runat="server" onchange="CheckAllInSection(this)" value="Check All" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkchild1" runat="server" value="Child 1" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkchild2" runat="server" value="Child 2" />
  </li>
</div>

---------Section 2 -----------
<div id="section2">
  <li class="carousel-border">
    <input class="not" type="checkbox" id="chkParent2" runat="server" onchange="CheckAllInSection(this)" value="Check All" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkchild3" runat="server" value="Child 3" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkchild4" runat="server" value="Child 4" />
  </li>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="Savecheckedvalueinhiddenfield()" value="GetCheckedId" />
```

js:

```
function Savecheckedvalueinhiddenfield() {
  var values = [];

  $(':checked:not(".not")').each(function() {
    values.push($(this).val());
  });

  alert(values.join());
}
```

Comment: i dont want every parent section value in hidden field that is check all and parent

Comment: your output is like this:Check All,Child 1,Child 2,Check All,Child 3,Child 4.In this output i dont want Check All.Just Child 1,Child 2,Child 3,Child 4

Comment: ok your answer is fine but consider if id`s are like this:abc,pqr and not chkParen1 and chkParent2 then

Comment: Thanks for an awesome answer

Comment: just last question to ask you like consider this checkbox are under one div name CheckboxList and i want that under this division with id CheckboxList  find all chekbox

Comment: Try something like `$('#CheckboxList ').find(':checked:not(".not")').each(...`

Answer (score 4):

you can make an array and loop through all checked checkboxes to update the array

```
var values = [];

$('input[type="checkbox"][id^="chkchild"]:checked').each(function(){
    values.push($(this).val());
});

alert(values);
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/n08645j1/5/)

Comment: i just want child 1 and child 2 and not check all if i am checking chkparent1 check all

Comment: yup this is working fine but what is my child checkbox id`s are like this:abc,pqr,lmn,xyz.So your solution will not work in this case